# Как скачать файл с помощью socket?

Tags: python-3.x, сокет

Как скачать файл с помощью socket? У меня есть скрипт, он работает. Архив (я качаю с помощью этого скрипта zip-архив) скачивается и содержит четыре файла типа json. Так вот при использовании данного скритпа, видимо архив не докачивается или ещё что-то, потому что один файл из архива не хочет распаковываться по причине:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/kivy/test.py", line 64, in <module>
    base.extractall("/home/kivy")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/zipfile.py", line 1347, in extractall
    self.extract(zipinfo, path, pwd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/zipfile.py", line 1335, in extract
    return self._extract_member(member, path, pwd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/zipfile.py", line 1397, in _extract_member
    with self.open(member, pwd=pwd) as source, \
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/zipfile.py", line 1261, in open
    fheader = zef_file.read(sizeFileHeader)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/zipfile.py", line 662, in read
    self._file.seek(self._pos)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Хотя стандартный архиватор Ubuntu показывает правильный размер поврежденного файла и размер самого архива верный. Подскажите, что не так с моим кодом? Интересует именно закачка файла с помощью socket. Вот данный скрипт:

```
import os
import re
import socket


sre_content_length = re.compile(r'Content-Length: *?(\d+)', re.I)


def load_file(url, path):
    load_file.flag = 1
    f = open(path, "wb")

    try:
        host, url = url.split('//', 1)[-1].split('/', 1)

        client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
        client.connect((socket.gethostbyname(host), 80))
        ss = 'GET /%s HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: %s\r\nUser-agent: Python\r\n\r\n' % (
            url, host
        )
        client.send(bytes(ss, 'UTF-8'))
        string = str(client.recv(1024)).split('\r\n')
        size = -1

        for t in range(len(string)):
            line = string[t]
            if not line or line.isspace():
                break
            if size == -1:
                mo = sre_content_length.match(line)
                if mo:
                    size = int(mo.group(1))

        header = '\r\n'.join(string[:t + 1])
        string = '\r\n'.join(string[t + 1:])
        up = header.split('\r\n')[0]

        if up.find('200') == -1:
            return False
        f.write(bytes(string, 'UTF-8'))

        while 1:
            assert load_file.flag
            t = client.recv(1024)
            if not t:
                break
            f.write(t)
        f.close()
        return True
    except:
        try:
            f.close()
            os.remove(path)
        except:
            pass
        return (-1, None)[load_file.flag]
```

Распаковываю архив так:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile("json.zip", "r") as base:
    base.extractall()
```

Штатный архиватор Ubuntu тоже не желает распаковывать именно один файл.

Comment: Скачивать с помощью socket - по-моему плохая идея

Comment: Другого варианта нет.